# Superpose a map and a region plot

Tags: map, plotting

I would like to add on a map of city a region plot, which is this one in this case :

```
ptins = {{100, 25.5}, {102, 24.5}, {104, 23.2}, {106, 22}, {108, 20.8}, 
         {110, 19}, {112, 17}, {116, 12}, {120, 6}, {124, -0.5}};
ptdes = {{100, 19}, {104, 18}, {108, 16}, {112, 12.5}, {116, 8}, {120, 2.5}};
ptsup = {{100, 6}, {104, 5.5}, {108, 4.5}, {112, 1}};
ptper = {{100, 1.5}, {104, 1.1}, {107, 0}};

ins = Interpolation[ptins]; 
des = Interpolation[ptdes]; 
sup = Interpolation[ptsup]; 
per = Interpolation[ptper];

limites = Plot[{ins[x], des[x], sup[x], per[x]}, {x, 100, 126}, 
   PlotRange -> {0, 28}, Filling -> Axis];

vibration[Q_, Kv_, Dis_, teta_] = (Kv*Abs[Sin[teta/2]] + Kv/10)*(Dis/(Q^(1/2)))^(-1.8); 
surpression[Q_, Ks_, Dis_, teta_] = 
    20*Log10[(Ks*Abs[Cos[teta/2]] + Ks/10)*(Dis/Q^(1/3))^(-1.2)/(20*10^-6)];

vibrationxy[Q_, Kv_, x_, y_] = 
  TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   vibration[Q, Kv, Dis, teta], {Dis, teta} -> {x, y}];
surpressionxy[Q_, Ks_, x_, y_] = 
  TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", 
   surpression[Q, Ks, Dis, teta], {Dis, teta} -> {x, y}];

Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= ins[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]], 
   vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= des[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]], 
   vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= sup[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]]}, {x, -400, 
   800}, {y, -800, 800}, PlotLegends -> Automatic], {Q, 1, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {Kv, 300, 6000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {Ks, 
  300, 6000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

is it possible ?

Thank you

Comment: Please take a moment to format your post for readability.  Click "edit" above, click on the (?) button in the top right, and follow the formatting instructions.  Make sure all code is in code blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing information about city coordinates and mapping of the x,y coordinates in your calculations to world coordinates, so that part of the question you have to work out yourself, but that shouldn't be to difficult.

Combining your plot with city data is not too difficult either.

First, to get a plot of the region you want, like Nancy, France (in V10):

```
city = GeoGraphics[ 
          GeoCenter -> GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Nancy", "Lorraine", "France"}]], 
          GeoRange -> 5*Quantity[1, "Kilometers"]
       ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can combine this with your plot using `Show`, but I'll demonstrate another option here, namely `Prolog` with `Inset`:

```
Manipulate[
 RegionPlot[{vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= 
    ins[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]], 
   vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= des[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]], 
   vibrationxy[Q, Kv, x, y] >= 
    sup[surpressionxy[Q, Ks, x, y]]}, {x, -400, 800}, {y, -800, 800}, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3],
  Prolog -> Inset[city, Center, Center, Scaled[{1, 1}]]], {Q, 1, 100, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {Kv, 300, 6000, 
  Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {Ks, 300, 6000, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

BTW I switched off the extrapolation warning messages using

```
Off[InterpolatingFunction::dmval]
```

but you'll probably have to look into that issue. You may be working beyond the range for which your interpolated points may yield reasonable values.